# draw graph by matplotlib in python

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, visualization

Here is my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12,8))
plt.xlabel('Time')
plt.ylabel('Number of Spared Bikes')
plt.plot(needs.index, needs['110'], label='#101')
plt.show()
```

What I need is a dataframe:

[image]

with this code, I got this graph:

[image]

As you can see the graph above, x axis looks awful.

I just want to make x axis by `time` index, not `2017-09-08 06:00`, but just like `06`.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: You need to update this data frame to take only hour part instead of complete datetime.

Comment: Is your index a `datetime64` type or an `object` type?

Comment: There were plenty of questions asked here about this problem before.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26700598/matplotlib-showing-x-tick-labels-overlapping-despite-best-efforts https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13515471/matplotlib-how-to-prevent-x-axis-labels-from-overlapping-each-other https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49231052/datetime-x-axis-matplotlib-labels-causing-uncontrolled-overlap

Comment: More possible duplicates: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14946371/editing-the-date-formatting-of-x-axis-tick-labels-in-matplotlib https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44213781/pandas-dataframe-line-plot-display-date-on-xaxis

Answer (score 0):

One way to approach it is to create a new column that has the data index reformatted to suit your needs.

Another way is to use [`matplotlib.xticks()`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.xticks.html) to define custom x axis labels

```
#apply custom processing on your label. rotarion='vertical' will give you even more space to place the labels
labels=needs.index.apply(lambda x: process_label(x)) 
#display the modified label
plt.xticks(needs.index, labels, rotation='vertical')
plt.plot(needs.index, data)
plt.show()
```