# Matplotlib major and minor ticks misaligned when using pandas date_range

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, date-range, xticks

I am trying to use pandas `date_range` in the x-axis of a matplotlib.pyplot graph, while setting years to be the major ticks and months to be the minor ticks (for a timeline plot).

I came across a seemingly unexpected behaviour (noticed also as part of [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26700598/matplotlib-showing-x-tick-labels-overlapping) but unsolved), where the ticks are not aligned, and they are exhibiting an offset.

This code reproduces it for me (v3.5.2):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

x_range = pd.date_range('2015-01-01', '2021-06-01', freq='m')
y = np.linspace(1,1, len(x_range))

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 1))
ax.plot(x_range, y)

loc = mdates.MonthLocator(interval=12)
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(loc)
ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(AutoMinorLocator(12))

fmt = mdates.DateFormatter('%Y')
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(fmt)
```

[image]

Anyone dealt with this before? I suspect it has to do with months having 28, 30 and 31 days but could not investigate further.

Comment: You can't use AutoMinorLocator if the major ticks are unevenly spaced: 
```
 Dynamically find minor tick positions based on the positions of
 major ticks. The scale must be linear with major ticks evenly spaced.
```
Just use a `MonthLocator` with `interval=1`.

Comment: Thanks! This seems to solve the example I gave! I'll accept your answer if you'd like!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do the following:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

x_range = pd.date_range('2015-01-01', '2021-06-01', freq='A')
y = np.linspace(1, 1, len(x_range))

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 1))
ax.plot(x_range, y)

loc = mdates.YearLocator()
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(loc)
ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(mdates.MonthLocator())

fmt = mdates.DateFormatter('%Y')
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(fmt)

plt.show()
```

[image]